# Store a Single Value Between Azure Timed Trigger

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I am new to Azure functions.

I want to run an Azure triggered function once every two hours. The function will normally take 1-2 minutes to execute. At the start of each run, I want to retreive the the id of the last record that was run. At the end of each run I want to store the updated value for the record id.

What is the most economical and simplest way to persist one interger value in between function calls?

Comment: Azure storage, look into it.

Comment: @Skin In your opinion Cosmos, Tables or something else?

Comment: Even just retrieving a blob and storing it with the relevant value. Cosmos would be overkill. You don’t even need to use tables, just blob will do the job. There are a million ways to skin a cat in this regard.

Comment: if you are using azure functions, you will need azure storage anyway: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code?tabs=bicep#storage-account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Azure Storage Account, Azure Function cannot be created.
The function fails if that storage account is deleted or that Storage account connection string is configured incorrectly in Azure Function App Configuration.

As the Users @*Skin* and @*BrunoLucasAzure* suggested that the blob container storage is the relevant solution to store the data in the blobs.

In this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp#supported-bindings) of Azure Functions Supported bindings, it is said that both Input and Output bindings are supported for the Azure Blob Storage.

> At the start of each run, I want to retreive the the id of the last record that was run. At the end of each run I want to store the updated value for the record id.

You can fetch the data stored in blob and send the required records to the blob file using input and output bindings with the suitable code and a practical example with the code on the context of **Daily Data upload to the blob using Azure Functions Timer Trigger** in this blog [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/timertrigger-azure-function-to-upload-to-azure-blob-daily-c4e761a8ee4c) given by the author @*SibeeshVenu*.